# Using fgets to get two lines on the same line

Tags: c

I am trying to print every two lines from file on the same line.

File looks like:

```
Supposedly there are over one
million words in the English Language
We trimmed some fat to take
away really odd words and determiners
```

I want to get:

```
Supposedly there are over one, million words in the English Language
We trimmed some fat to take, away really odd words and determiners
```

I used the fgets() function so far to display the data from .txt file but i dont know how to get the every two lines of .txt file on same line. I am getting the same output.

```
char line[110]; // max numbers of characters in line
while (fgets(line, 109, stdin)) {
    printf("%s", line);
}
return 0;
```

I expect output to be like I mentioned before:

```
Supposedly there are over one, million words in the English Language
We trimmed some fat to take, away really odd words and determiners
```

Comment: One problem should be quite easy to guess about if you just look at the actual output. Please read more about [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and what it adds to the buffer.

Comment: And doing something every second, third, fourth, etc. time is something that just about any text-book, tutorial or class should have had as an exercise quite early I would think. What do you know about the modulo operator `%`? Have you used it before? If not then I recommend you read about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove trailing `\n` from the buffer for odd line number then print it.

```
  int lineNumber = 1;
  char line[110]; // max numbers of characters in line

  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin))
  {
          if (lineNumber&1) {

               char *pos;
               if ((pos=strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL) {
                   *pos = '\0';
                    printf("%s ",line);
               }
           }
           else {
               printf (" %s", line);
           }
           lineNumber++;
   }
```

Comment: Can i ask you, is there any code to somehow store every two lines to one string?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char line[110]; // max numbers of characters in line

    for(int i = 0; fgets(line, 109, stdin); i = (i+1) % 2)
    {
        int l = strlen(line);
        if (l > 0) line[l - 1] = 0;
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("%s, ",line);
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *testData = fopen("C:\\path\\file.txt", "r+");
lineCounter = 0;
char *lineFileTest = new char[1024];
char *lineFileTestTemp = new char[1024];
while( fgets(lineFileTestTemp, 1024, testData) != NULL ) {
    if((lineCounter&1)==0?1:0){
        lineFileTest = lineFileTestTemp;
    }
    else{
        lineFileTest += lineFileTestTemp;
        printf("%s", lineFileTest);
    }
    lineCounter++;
}
fclose(testData);
if(lineFileTest || lineFileTestTemp){
    free(lineFileTest);
    free(lineFileTestTemp);
}
```